# download file exception handling

Tags: java

In my application I download several critical files from  a server, and I want to write some code that handles the case where the a file download didn't complete for a reason or other ,to retry downloading it at next startup. The function that downloads a file at a time however throws only MalformedURLException and IOException , but if these exceptions are thrown that means that the download didn't even begin. How should I arrange things so I can treat the case where a download failed , even if it began ?

```
void download(String file) throws MalformedURLException ,IOException 
{

        BufferedInputStream getit = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(file).openStream());
        FileOutputStream saveit = new FileOutputStream(DOWNLOAD_PATH+fileName+"."+ZIP_EXTENSION);
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(saveit,1024);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int readed = getit.read(data,0,1024);
        while(readed != -1)
        {
            bout.write(data,0,readed);
            readed = getit.read(data,0,1024);
        }
        bout.close();
        getit.close();
        saveit.close();

}
```

Comment: Did you write the download function, or is it from an existing library?

Comment: it's my custom download function

Answer (score 2):

You might be better using the `Jakarta Commons HttpClient` API.

However, for your custom function take a look at `InterruptedIOException` and `bytesTransferred` on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html

```
public class InterruptedIOException
extends IOException

Signals that an I/O operation has been interrupted. 

The field bytesTransferred indicates how many bytes were successfully transferred before the interruption occurred.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your download is synchronous, you should be able to add an appropriate exception (or return an appropriate value) to indicate failure.

If your download is asynchronous, consider using the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You can pass in an observer implementation as an extra parameter to your download method.

The observer in your case (for example) might look something like:

```
public interface FileDownloadObserver
{
  public void downloadFailed(String file, Object error);
  public void downloadSucceeded(String file);
}
```

Then the download method would look like:

```
void download(String file, FileDownloadObserver observer)
    throws MalformedURLException, IOException
```

This is all assuming you can actually detect that the download failed. If not, you might have to provide some more information about how you're doing the download.

Comment: I guess then you could interpret any problem (other than the existing exceptions) as "download failed", and define a "download failed" exception as well. Or use @josek's suggestion. (Also, are you not storing/returning any of the downloaded data because it's just an example of your method?)